# TIdHttp not work method post empty body - Delphi

Tags: http, delphi, post, request, indy

I have a problem when trying to make a request using the POST method when there is no information in the body, how do I use POST without having Parameters/Body ?

I tried to pass empty, but the code below returns the following error:

> HTTP/1.1 500

```
try
  responseres := tstringlist.Create;
  retorno := TstringStream.Create;
  params := tstringlist.Create;
  //--------------------------------
  IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization']     := 'Bearer ' + txtAccessToken.Text;
  IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['x-integration-key'] := 'GYBtKWR5QjSwVxXXXxxXxXeUeOsUe0nOuc8HyTnyT1s';
  //--------------------------------
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Charset     := 'utf-8';
  //--------------------------------
  IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.onvio.com.br/dominio/integration/v1/activation/enable', params, retorno);
  JsonResponse        := TJSONObject.ParseJsonValue(UTF8Decode(retorno.DataString)) as TJSONObject;
  IntegrationKey.Text := JsonResponse.GetValue<string>('integrationKey');

  MemoJson.Lines.Text := responseres.Text;
finally
  params.Free;
  responseres.Free;
end;
```

In postman, this works:

[image: postman_img]

Comment: How do you know that it's the empty body that is causing the error?

Comment: @DaveNottage   I imagine, because other requests that have the informed body work

Comment: What `Content-Type` does Postman send when the `Body` is set to `none`? What does the actual HTTP request look like, compared to what `TIdHTTP` sends? `TIdHTTP` handles an empty `TStringList` just fine, and should be sending `Content-Length: 0` with no body. Alternatively, if you really don't want to send a body, you can just pass in `nil` for the `ASource` parameter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  No postman is used "none". nil didn't work

Comment: What are the hidden headers in PostMan?

Comment: @hugolmf I seriously doubt that Postman would send `Content-Type: none` when `Body` is set to `none`. What does it ACTUALLY send? Also, you didn't answer my earlier question. What does Postman's raw HTTP request actually look like when `Body` is `none`, compared to `TIdHTTP`'s raw request when `ASource` is `nil` or empty? This makes a big difference in solving your issue.

Comment: @DaveNottage  These are the ones, but I've tried to add them too, but I still get the error

Content-Length = 0
User-Agent = PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept = */*
Accept-Encoding = gzip, deflate, br
Connection = keep-alive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve it thanks to your help **@Remy Lebeau**, **@Robert**, **@Dave Nottage**. Thank you so much !!

**SOLUTION:**

```
 retorno     := TstringStream.Create;
 params      := nil;
 responseres := TStringlist.Create;

 IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
 IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization']     := 'Bearer ' + txtAccessToken.Text;
 IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['x-integration-key'] := 'GYBtKWR5QjSwVxXXXxxXxXeUeOsUe0nOuc8HyTnyT1s';
 IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Content-Length']    := '0';
 IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Accept']            := '*/*';
 IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Accept-Encoding']   := 'gzip, deflate, br';
 IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Connection']        := 'keep-alive';

 IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType       := 'application/json';
 IdHTTP1.Request.Charset           := 'utf-8';

 IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.onvio.com.br/dominio/integration/v1/activation/enable', params, retorno);
 JsonResponse        := TJSONObject.ParseJsonValue(UTF8Decode(retorno.DataString)) as TJSONObject;
 IntegrationKey.Text := JsonResponse.GetValue<string>('integrationKey');

 MemoJson.Lines.Text := FormatJSON(retorno.DataString);
 JsonToDataset(FDMemTable1, '['+retorno.DataString+']');
```

Comment: Why are you using `Request.CustomHeaders` for things that are provided as native properties in `Request`? Change `Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Content-Length'] := '0';` => `Request.ContentLength := 0;` (which `Post()` already does for you, BTW) ... `Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Accept'] := '*/*';` => `Request.Accept := '*/*';` ... `Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Accept-Encoding'] := 'gzip, deflate, br';` => `Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate, br';` ... `Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Connection'] := 'keep-alive';` => `Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';`

Comment: On a side note, unless you are actually implementing your own compression logic, you should not be setting the `Accept-Encoding` header at all.  Indy does not implement `br` compression, but it does implement `gzip` and `deflate`, if you assign a compressor object to the `TIdHTTP.Compressor` property. Let `TIdHTTP` manage the `Accept-Encoding` header for you, based on its actual capabilities.

Comment: On another side note, since you are receiving a JSON string from `Post()`, you should use the overloaded version that returns a `String` instead of fills a `TStream`, let `TIdHTTP` handle the charset decoding for you, eg: `var JsonStr: string; ... JsonStr := IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.onvio.com.br/dominio/integration/v1/activation/enable', params); JsonResponse := TJSONObject.ParseJsonValue(JsonStr) as TJSONObject; ...`

Answer (score -3):

Use nil as body:
params := nil;  //instead of tstringlist.Create;

Also, you need to free "retorno" and "JsonResponse" objects.

Comment: I changed it, but it still has the same error: HTTP/1.1 500
params      := nil;

    IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization']     := 'Bearer ' + txtAccessToken.Text;
    IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['x-integration-key'] := 'GYBtKWR5QjSwVxXXXxxXxXeUeOsUe0nOuc8HyTnyT1s';
    IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Content-Length']    := '0';

    IdHTTP1.Post('https://api.onvio.com.br/dominio/integration/v1/activation/enable', params, retorno);

Comment: MemoJson.Lines.Text := retorno.Text; //you will at least see the error message

Comment: Also, Post() sets Content-Length, so don't add it as custom header.
Also, set content type=application/octet-stream, otherwise Post() might set it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which might not be appreciated on the server side.

Comment: @Robert `MemoJson.Lines.Text := retorno.Text; //you will at least see the error message` - Not if `Post()` raises an exception on the `500` error (which is its default behavior).